# Adding Button to LinearLayout don't work

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add button to LinearLayout programmaticly, but application crash:

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/main_view" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="onClickBtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code:

```
package com.chovanec.runo;

import android.os.Bundle; // and more

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
        return true;
    }

    public void onClickBtn(View v)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(getBaseContext());
        btn.setText("New Button");

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        l.addView(btn);

    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
04-14 03:09:00.150: D/AndroidRuntime(7375): Shutting down VM
04-14 03:09:00.150: W/dalvikvm(7375): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415102a0)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3691)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     ... 11 more
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     at com.chovanec.runo.MainActivity.onClickBtn(MainActivity.java:37)
04-14 03:09:00.155: E/AndroidRuntime(7375):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: which is your line 37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be  `LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);`

You also miss `android:orientation="vertical"` in your linear layout that is why the new button did not appear. Unless you want your buttons to appear side by side then you have to change `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in your button xml

and you cannot use

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
```

unless it is a relative layout.

Comment: I edited my answer to show why the new button did not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
 Button btn = new Button(this);
```

instead of:

```
 Button btn = new Button(getBaseContext());
```

**Update:**

and try to add the button to the inner `LinearLayout`:

```
 LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
```

instead of:

```
 LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I don't think you can add a button directly to the activity layout.

Comment: this don't help, still crash

Answer (score 1):

Your `LinearLayout l` is actually **null**.

Change this:

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
```

To this:

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
```

Comment: what the point in giving an answer that was already given twice?

Comment: this change is good (prevent crashing) but new button not appears

Comment: And the other one? invisible?

Comment: @EmilAdz what's the point of editing your own answer by observing someone else's answer?

Comment: I'm not talking about my answer. @Hoan Nguyen gave the same answer as well.

Comment: @EmilAdz but your answer was wrong at the time that Waqas give his answer

Comment: @Waqas, I edited my answer because it was wrong, and I'm not asking any credit for it. But Hoan Nguyen gave the right answer at the same time I wrote mine. you wrote same one 4 minutes after.

Comment: @EmilAdz Hoan Nguyen didn't answer correctly at first time, however he updated his answer within 5 minutes window, and I believe I answered before he corrected his.

Comment: @Waqas, if this is the case then I'm sorry. my bad.

Comment: @EmilAdz Its not my style to answer a question if it already has been. Anyhow, good to know you realized it :)

Comment: @Waqas I realized I forgot the R.id and when I came back to edit your answer is already there, a check should go to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
l.addView(btn);
```

findViewById expect an id of view element You give it layout id.

Try this

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

or

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
```